# How to make an object move endlessly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move an object from position A to position B on X axis endlessly. But it does move and comeback only once. How to make it continuosly? I've tried Vector3.Lerp or just creating new Vector3 but it only teleports.

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 firstPosition = new Vector3(-14f, 2.5f, 17f);
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 secondPosition = new Vector3(14f, 2.5f, 17f);
    
   
    public float speed = 10f;
  

    void Start()
    {
       transform.position = firstPosition;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {

      

      
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, secondPosition, Time.deltaTime * speed);
       
        if(transform.position == secondPosition)
        {
            secondPosition = firstPosition;
        }

       



    }
}
```

`

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use Unity, but since nobody else answered....

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 firstPosition = new Vector3(-14f, 2.5f, 17f);
    [SerializeField] private Vector3 secondPosition = new Vector3(14f, 2.5f, 17f);
    private Vector3 target;

    public float speed = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
       transform.position = firstPosition;
       target = secondPosition;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, Time.deltaTime * speed);
       
        if (transform.position == firstPosition)
        {
            target = secondPosition;
        }
        else if (transform.position == secondPosition)
        {
            target = firstPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay great it works! But can u tell me why I have to create another variable to make it work? Why do I need to create target?

Comment: In  your original code when you do `secondPosition = firstPosition;`, you overwrite `secondPosition` variable and the original value of it is lost. You end up having both `firstPosition` and `secondPosition` pointing to the same location.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative you could also use [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) like e.g.

```
// By default afaik a full cycle takes 2 seconds so in order to normalize
// this to one second we will divide by this times 2 later
public float cycleDuration = 1;

private void Update ()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(firstPosition, secondPosition, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time / (cycleDuration * 2f), 1f));
}
```

In case your object is spawned later in the game you might want to rather always start at the first position and do

```
private float timer;

private void Update ()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(firstPosition, secondPosition, Mathf.PingPong(timer / (cycleDuration * 2f), 1f));

    timer += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Comment: I figured their might be a built-in way to do it but, like I said, I don't use Unity. +1

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yours is actually as valid and I would go with that if I rather want to control/configure a fixed move speed instead of a fixed loop duration .. and yes thanks ^^ typing on the phone ^^